# Why is the live wire connected to the coil on this transformer?

Tags: transformer

Mains (230v) is connected to "L" (live) and "N" (neutral) and the voltage regulated device is connected to "1" and "2".

"1" (white) is connected to the live wire (brown) and "2" is connected to the neutral wire (blue).

The voltage regulation happens on the neutral side (grey/red).

What I cannot understand is why the live wire (white) is also connected to the coil. Isn't this connection redundant?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Documentation from the manufacturer:

[image]

Comment: This was answered in your previous question.  Have you looked up about auto-transformers? - https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/601222/how-does-electricity-flow-in-this-transformer

Comment: I don't see where this question is answered there. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Is it correctly understood that the coil needs the live connection to create the needed magnetic field to be able to voltage regulate the neutral?

Comment: It is a transformer, you cant leave one end of the transformer's coil disconnected.  Did you read the wikipedia page about it that I linked in my answer?

Comment: The transformer is connected as autotransformer, what is the answer to you question. Additional info can be fine at link, provided in comment above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All mains transformers need neutral and live to operate. The AC mains input coil creates the magnetic field so that the magnetig fields generate voltage on the other coils. An autotransformer is no different.

Answer (score 1):

It's an autotransformer-based fan speed regulator.

[image]

The autotransformer is connected, across the 230 V ~ supply, through an on-off switch.

Fan speed (voltage) is selected using the tap selector switch.